# Position an Overlay Image onto Canvas

Tags: android, imageview, android-canvas, android-bitmap

Hello There I am working on an Android Application that takes an Image from the gallery and add a watermarks on it. It has the following features:

- **The Screen is manually locked to portrait mode by me in manifest.xml**
- The user can drag the water mark to any desired location on the screen
- The water mark image is being added on the user's image
- The user can save the image with the desired water mark

---

### The Water Mark xml

```
<RelativeLayout
   xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent"

   <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="10"
        android:id="@+id/root">

        <FrameLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/pic_holder">


        </FrameLayout>

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:id="@+id/watermark"
            />

    </RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

---

**ImageView Added as**

```
    image_watermark=(ImageView)v.findViewById(R.id.watermark);
    mRrootLayout = (ViewGroup) v.findViewById(R.id.root);

    mRrootLayout.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);

    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(300, 300);

    image_watermark.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
    image_watermark.setImageResource(R.drawable.cat8);
    image_watermark.setOnTouchListener(this);

    //the R.drawable.cat8 is a sample image i'm using
    //The drawable width and height would be 600*600 pixels all the time as I am using this same size for all imageview water mark drawables
```

---

### The imageview watermark can be drag as

```
 @Override
public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent event) {
    final int X = (int) event.getRawX();
    final int Y = (int) event.getRawY();
    switch (event.getAction() & MotionEvent.ACTION_MASK) {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lParams = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) view.getLayoutParams();
            _xDelta = X - lParams.leftMargin;
            _yDelta = Y - lParams.topMargin;
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
            xloc=X;
            yloc=Y;
            //to check the location
            Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Location==="+X+"==="+Y, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_DOWN:
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_UP:
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) view
                    .getLayoutParams();
            layoutParams.leftMargin = X - _xDelta;
            layoutParams.topMargin = Y - _yDelta;
            layoutParams.rightMargin = -250;
            layoutParams.bottomMargin = -250;
            view.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
            break;
    }
    mRrootLayout.invalidate();
    return true;
}
```

**This method is working alright (from my side its working well for me)**

---

### The water mark is added on image as

```
//get the image from the user
//may be of any width and height any resolution
BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
Bitmap mBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(data, 0, data.length, options);

 //add the water mark to the camera photo bitmap here
 Bitmap mutableBitmap = mBitmap.copy(Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888, true);

 image_watermark.buildDrawingCache();
 Bitmap bmap = image_watermark.getDrawingCache();

 Paint pai=new Paint();
 pai.setAntiAlias(true);

 //get the location of image view water mark on screen
 int[] posXY = new int[2];
 image_watermark.getLocationOnScreen(posXY)
 xloc = posXY[0];
 yloc = posXY[1];

 //create the image view water mark on the image got by user
 // problem is here
 //the water mark is placed not accurately onto the target location where the user drops it
 //it happens differently on multiple devices       
 Bitmap final_image=Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bmap,
                        image_watermark.getMeasuredWidth()*5,
                        image_watermark.getMeasuredHeight()*5,false);

 Canvas canvas = new Canvas(mutableBitmap);
 canvas.drawBitmap(final_image,((image_watermark.getWidth()*2)+xloc),(yloc), pai);

 //save the mutable image as so far
```

---

### The Problem

The problem is that the water mark image in not positioned on the target set by the user

Example:
This is the Initial position for the image view on the image loaded by the user:
[image]

This is the result image after user saves the image applying the water mark on:
[image]

Comment: I have the same issue, my image is offset where the target should be. Did you try adjusting the GroundOverlayOption Position

Comment: @Android Nerd Have you solved this issue ? If yes can you update the answer to your question